# How to escape entire block with html-entities via twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, html-entities, html-encode

I want to create an xml output that contains html encoded block.

This is my twig snipplet:

```
<rawXml>
    <message>
        {% autoescape 'html' %}
            <ThisShouldBeEscaped>
                <ButItIsnt>Dang</ButItIsnt>
            </ThisShouldBeEscaped>
        {% endautoescape %}
    </message>
</rawXml>
```

On rendering, I expected to message content to be html-encoded this way:

```
&lt;ThisShouldBeEscaped&gt;
    &lt;ButItIsnt&gt;Dang&lt;/ButItIsnt&gt;
&lt;/ThisShouldBeEscaped&gt;
```

yet I get a complete raw XML response:

```
<rawXml>
    <message>
        <ThisShouldBeEscaped>
            <ButItIsnt>Dang</ButItIsnt>
        </ThisShouldBeEscaped>
    </message>
</rawXml>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://twigfiddle.com/mtey4z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig does not by default escape template markup. If you wish to escape your HTML in this way, then set it to a variable first and then either `autoescape` it, or use a regular `escape`:

```
<rawXml>
    <message>
        {% set myHtml %}
        <ThisShouldBeEscaped>
            <ButItIsnt>Dang</ButItIsnt>
        </ThisShouldBeEscaped>
        {% endset %}
        {% autoescape 'html' %}
            {{ myHtml }}
        {% endautoescape %}
        <!-- or -->
        {{ myHtml|escape }}
    </message>
</rawXml>
```